# How to filter elements from the list by checking elements' powers?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

From the list PointsInSpace I would like to select all the elemets that are inside the circle with selected radius.

The class XY members are

```
double x,
double y
```

So for the selected radius `r` with centre at `(0,0)` I would have to check which element le from the List PointsInSpace satisfies the following condition

```
Math.Pow(le.x,2) + Math.Pow(le.y, 2) <= Math.Pow(r,2)
```

Does anyone know how to filter all elements from the list that satisfy the condition using lambda expressions or any simple way that doesn't require first calculating the powers and then filtering?

I was thinking about implementing something like the following (pseudocode):

```
pointsInCircleRange = PointsInSpace.Where(d => Math.Pow(d.x, 2)) + Math.Pow(d.y, 2)) <= Math.Pow(r,2))
```

The line above certainly has errors. I would be very thankful if anyone suggested a similar way to fitler elements by their powers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks to me you only have problem with brackets in the expression. 
Try this:

```
pointsInCircleRange =PointsInSpace.Where(d => Math.Pow(d.x, 2) + Math.Pow(d.y, 2) <= Math.Pow(r,2));
```